# swf file working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php, html

```
 //pagination function
        public function pagination($per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '', $total){
        $adjacents = "2";
        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {
            $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li class='active' ><a >$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a >$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";
        }
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a >$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";
        }
        else
        {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li class='active'><a >$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>";
        }
        }
        }
    
        if ($page < $counter - 1){
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$next'>Next</a></li>";
        // $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
        }else{
        //$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
        // $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
        }
    
        }
        return $pagination;
        }






   
    public function Recipe_list()
    {
      
         $jpag= new Customer_Recipes;
         /*------------------------------pagination------------------------------*/
         $page=1;
         $limit=15;
         $start=0;
         if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!='')
         {
              $page=$_GET['page'];
         }
         $start=($page-1)*$limit;   

        
         $rows = $customermodel->count_recipes($Cat,$Sub,$uid);
         if($rows>0)
           $jb = $customermodel->get_recipes($Cat,$Sub,$uid,$start,$limit);
                 }

?>
<div class="row">
            <div class="md-12"> <ul class="pagination">
               <?php
                     echo $jpag->pagination($limit,$page,URL."Customer_Recipes/Recipe_list/?Cat=$Cat&Sub=$Sub&uid=$uid&page=",$rows);
               ?>
           </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: check path to swf file

Comment: it is correct , if i give the image path of same location it loads

Comment: put the absolute path as like this xyz.com/swf/0.swf

Comment: try www.urdomain.com/swf/0.swf and check what it shows

Comment: changed path to .urdomain.com/swf/0.swf but no result

Comment: can you provide domain name ?

Comment: its working perfectly here

Comment: it must be browser issue

Answer (score 1):

Note: This question has nothing to do with SWFObject, the SWFObject tag should be removed.

If the SWF file is working locally but not on the server, check the following:

1. Is the file uploaded to the correct directory?
2. Does the file have the correct permissions on the server?
3. Is the server configured to support the `application/x-shockwave-flash` MIME type?

Number 3 is a common gotcha for servers that have not previously served SWF files.

This assumes the HTML/CSS/JS is identical on both the local machine and the server, the same web browser is being used to test the local file and the server file, the web server is accessible, and the HTML file loads (but the SWF does not).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you uploaded it to the right place, and it's permissions are set correctly. I know some swf have licensing mechanisms that do allow you to run on localhost but require some form of license to run on a specific url.

Comment: so u want to say i need to change permission

Comment: video? app? animation? what?

Comment: it is a file with extension swf having animation

Comment: is it loading as a resource when you load the page?

Comment: did you make the file? where did you get it?

Comment: i have not made that file